# Strict Properties Without Option Strict On

Tags: vb.net, properties, implicit-conversion, setter, strict

When `Option Strict` is turned Off, which is the default for my application, VB will automatically convert the value when property is String. It appears to call the toString() of the incoming value's Object. I believe casting will work for any property that can be safely casted (eg integer to double). I want the properties to behave in a strict manner, in that the Type passed MUST match the type on the declared property.

Is there a way to make Objects Properties Strict at the Object level without having to resort to the `Option Strict On` configuration on?

For example:

```vb
Option Strict Off
Class TestObj
    Private _foo As String
    Public Property Foo as String
        Get
            Return _foo
        End Get
        Set(v As String)
            console.write(String.format("v = <{0}> {1}", v.GetType().FullName, v))
            _foo = v
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Dim o as new TestObj()
o.Foo = "some_str"
o.Foo = 1234
o.Foo = DateTime.now()
```

In the above case, all values are converted to Strings at arrival to the setter:

```
v = <System.String> some_str
v = <System.String> 1234
v = <System.String> 7/7/2022 8:22:49 PM
```

I am aware of `DynamicObject` and ability to tightly control setters like Python's `__setattr__` but this breaks autocomplete functionality in editors as it would preclude defining properties on the class to get the functionality.

Comment: Really Option Strict Should be on, should be the default and only ever tuned off in very very rare situations.  Perhaps you could move the stuff that Option Strict interferes with into a partial class where you can turn Option Strict Off for the one code file?

Comment: *"Option Strict is turned Off, which is the default for my application"*. That's your mistake, right there. You should ALWAYS set `Option Strict On` at the project level. You should set it `On` in the VS options specifically so that it will be `On` by default for all new projects. If you ever need to use late-binding then you should set `Option Strict Off` at the file level and only for those files that specifically need it. Even then, you should use use partial classes to keep the code in files with `Option Strict Off` to an absolute minimum.

Comment: If you're determined to do things the wrong way then you can always go the other way around, i.e. have `Option Strict Off` at the project level and then use partial classes and set `Option Strict On` at the file level for specific code that you want. Basically, Microsoft provide the means to get the results you want so use it, instead of expecting to get those results some other way.

Comment: Thanks for replies. Regarding Strict, unfortunately I'm an obscene amount of legacy code that I did not write. I personally would have written in C#.

Comment: It's also worth noting that this has absolutely nothing to do with the properties. Those properties are type `String` so they receive a `String`. What's happening is that the system is calling `ToString` on the object assigned to the property BEFORE the assignment is made. The property has no idea that the value originally assigned is anything other than a `String`. It's the code doing the assignment that is at issue, not the code of the property. There's no such thing as a property that isn't "strict". The same goes for method parameters.

Comment: If you go to the project properties, on the "Compile" ply, there are individual items under "Warning configurations" that you can toggle between ignored, warning, or error.  The "Implicit conversion" option should cover the particular item you're concerned about.  Note that it doesn't have the granularity to discriminate between properties and other variables, this will capture all implicit conversions anywhere in the application.  The warning configurations will cover most (but **not** all) of the things that are captured by `Option Strict On`.

Comment: Note that a particular risk with `Option Strict Off` is that if there are any mismatches in the handler signature on event handlers added with `AddHandler`, they cannot be unsubscribed.  `Option Strict On` is the only way to catch this reliably in my experience, none of the warning configuration options would catch it.  I can sympathize with your situation, I write new code as `Option Strict On` (except when I forget to flip it), but I work with a large volume of legacy code written without it which isn't practical to bring into line.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly agree with the commenters that `Option Explicit On` and `Option Strict On` are simply a must - as the default settings of Visual Studio for new VB projects as well as for each project within the solution(s) you took over.

I my opinion one has to invest first some effort into clean-up work when taking over legacy solutions including

- Add an ".editorconfig" if there isn't any
- Convert the projects to SDK projects where possible
- Go through the code and

  - format the code to your liking using the current naming convention where possible
  - correct/complement/remove/translate-to-English the documentation comments
  - add some `//TODO:`  - comments where refactoring is needed wherever you notice a code repetition, repeated property access, huge methods that needs to be split into smaller parts, if-not-condition-then-else that needs to be reverted etc. but don't code it yet - these refactorings could introduce some bugs, we need to finish the next step first.
  - put every top-level type in its own file (except overloaded generic types of the same name) and make sure the type name matches the file name
- Go through the unit tests and fix them, remove unnecessary ones and complement the missing ones.
- Change all projects to `Option Explicit On`, `Option Strict On` and `Option Compare Binary` (use explicit `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` / `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` where needed). (`Option Infer On` or `Off`, what you prefer). If you hate to have 1000s of errors, add an `Option Strict Off` on top of each VB file which you later removed again file by file, otherwise do a bulk mutation.
- Fix all compile errors (per file or bulk mutation)
- Run unit tests, fix code of failing tests (repeat this after each of the following steps)
- Update the .NET framework version if possible (e.g. to current or .NET 4.8)
- Update the NuGet packages
- Do all the previously tagged refactorings
- Enable the analyzer warnings
- Fix all the warnings and infos or suppress them, individually or in the project file by adding the according entry to the `<NoWarn>` element.
- Start implementing the changes why you originally cloned the repository...

Of course that comes with a price but not doing it also has its price - I'm certain you are going to find dozens of little mistakes in the original code during the process of going `Strict`. And the time one spends formatting the code files is not just wasted time neither as in the process one also learns to understand the code...